# While uploading files using FTP in Jenkins, some files will be corrupted

Tags: c#, jenkins, ftp

I've set up Jenkins server in the office (1 master server@Windows server 2012 R2 & 2 nodes@Windows 10 Professional 64bits) for deploying web applications automatically. Web applications are deployed to IIS Server via FTP (FileZilla Server v0.9.41 beta, I know it's old but the administrator doesn't allow me to update the version).

Recently, after uploading files to server, sometimes few files (larger than 8k bytes) are corrupted. Sometimes they are binary files (dll files) and sometimes they are text files (Javascript files). The only observation I found is that the missing bytes in those corrupted files are 8K bytes times.

For instance, upload 3 files: A.dll (100K bytes), B.js (25K bytes), C.dll (200K bytes).
First time the corrupted file may be A.dll and its size is only 84K bytes at server.
Next time the corrupted file may be B.js and its size is only 17K bytes.
The missing bytes are not the beginning or end parts in those corrupted files, they may occur in any position in files.

The corrupted files might exist in any subfolder and the FTP server showed that the uploading process were correct.

I've tried using Jenkins plugin "Publish Over FTP Plugin" and WinSCP.exe for FTP uploading (using Jenkins Windows Batch Shell) but this error still occurs occasionally.

I've also written a C# application using WinSCP.dll for the uploading actions but the error is still not resolved. No matter files are uploaded from Jenkins master or slave nodes, it still exists.

However, if I uploaded to the FTP server manually via any FTP client (such as FileZilla FTP Client, any version), all files could be uploaded properly.

```
        SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
        {
            Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
            HostName = serverAddr,
            UserName = FTP_USER_NAME,
            Password = FTP_USER_PASSWORD[serverKey],
        };

    using (Session session = new Session())
        {
            session.Open(sessionOptions);

            switch (action)
            {
                case FTPActionType.Upload:
                    {
                        session.PutFiles(localPath.Replace(@"/", @"\"), remotePath.Replace(@"\", @"/"));

                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
```

I expect that all files could be uploaded to FTP server properly in Jenkins; no files are corrupted.

Comment: And what is `Session` exactly

Comment: Log file please (`Session.SessionLogPath`).

Comment: @TheGeneral it's WinSCP.Session from WinSCP library.

Comment: @Martin Prikryl, ok, I've add the log setting in code. I will show you the error log next time it happens, thanks.

Comment: *"if I uploaded to the FTP server manually via any FTP client ... all files could be uploaded properly"* - If that includes WinSCP, post also an equivalent WinSCP GUI session log file showing a successful upload.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Please download log from https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vbDJAKWmrzH-HC9aPGLr0kzBKHfx6LXe/view  At line 1490, bootstrap-datepicker.min.js is uploaded to FTP server. The original size is 43358 bytes. However, the size of this file at FTP server is only 26974 bytes. Sorry about that I have only FileZilla FTP Client on my computer so I cannot provide the correct log file for you.

Comment: Can you add `session.ListDirectory(remotePath.Replace(@"\", @"/")` to your code and post a new log file? + Post at least a verbose FileZilla log file.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I will show you the log tomorrow later. In addition, you can check my replied post for updated status, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After I re-install one of nodes with Windows 7 Professional 64bits and set it up for deployment, everything works perfectly on it...

I don't know why because the machine(hardware) is the same one. The only difference is OS.
So in my guess, maybe it's the issue of network adapter driver?

I will conduct more stress tests on this win7 machine and check if it could work all the time, thanks for everybody.